# Symfony2 ImageUpload and Retrieval from the Database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Please can someone assist I want o retrieve image from the database using the below code in symfony2 and php: this is my controller action:

```
public function showImageContentAction($id) {
    header('Content-type:image/jpg');
    $image = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('xxxBundle:UploadSource')
        ->find($id);
    $im = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image->getImage()));
    imagejpeg($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}//end of image restore controller
```

And this is in my twig template:

```
<img src="{{ path('show_image_content', {id: img_id}) }}" />
```

When I run the above the code I get an error something like:
Attempted to call method "getImage" on class "Project\xxxBundle\Entity UploadSource". And this is my Routing.yml file:
    show_image_content: pattern: /images/content/{id} 
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectLagosBundle:Default:showImageContent }

Comment: Then your entity for the image, does not have a method called "getImage". You must add it.

Comment: Am kind of not getting things well at that point. Just dont know how to override this method to retrieve the image stored on my db as string as per the symfony2 documentation. thanks in view of your help.

Comment: You wouldn't be overriding any methods, it'd simply be adding a method in this case. If you could add the full error message to your question it may help you get an answer.

Comment: This is my full error message:Attempted to call method "getImage" on class "Project\xxxBundle\Entity\Document" in C:\wamp\www\LagosAgenda2\src\Project\xxxBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 176.

Comment: I believe this problem will help alot of Programmers out there who might be facing the same challenge

Comment: I think it may help people who are at the very early stages of learning PHP / programming. The error message is fairly self-explanatory. Open up the class "Profile\xxxBundle\Entity\Document", and add a `getImage()` method, and give it the behaviour that you want. You can't just make up methods on objects, they have to exist. Perhaps instead of jumping straight into Symfony, you should learn some basic OO PHP. Perhaps try codecademy, or a similar resource - this is an incredibly basic problem, and you need to at the least try to solve it on your own before seeking help here.

Comment: Okay, I was able to resolve that error by using my accessor function as specified in my Document class. But however I get this error:Warning: file_get_contents(553a869754859.jpeg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\xxxAgenda\src\Project\xxxBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 183

Comment: Please dont bother anymore! I have solved my problem thanks for everything. Thanks once again